# Logstash issue while following elastic documentation

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

As part of a training project, I am trying to setup a single instance of Logstash and test in standalone according to the elasticssearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/advanced-pipeline.html). I triggered a Docker instance of Logstash.
Everything went well until I got stuck at that point:

bin/logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --config.reload.automatic

I am facing the following error:

`Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory.  If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting`

and when I specify a path : `bin/logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --path.data data2 --config.reload.automatic`

I have an other error:  `Error: Address already in use`

I have exactly the same conf as it's stated in the above documentation URL.

I tryed lot of combination but Iam running out of idea.

Thank you for the hands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages you're encountering in Logstash are related to two issues:

1. "Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory."
   This error suggests that Logstash is trying to use the same data directory as another running instance.
   To resolve this, you need to specify a different data directory for each Logstash instance. You can do this using the --path.data option when starting Logstash. For example:

   `bin/logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --path.data /path/to/first/instance/data`
2. "Error: Address already in use"
   This error occurs when Logstash is trying to use a network address (port) that is already being used by another process on your system.
   To fix this, you should specify a different network port for Logstash to use. You can do this by editing your Logstash configuration file (first-pipeline.conf) and changing the port setting to a different, available port.

- Locate the logstash.yml configuration file for the second instance of Logstash.
- Open the logstash.yml file in a text editor.
- Search for or add the following line to specify the HTTP port for Logstash. By default, Logstash uses port 9600 for its HTTP API:
- Add `http.port: 9700` (9700 is just an example) Save the logstash.yml file.
- Start the second instance of Logstash using the -f flag to specify the configuration file, and make sure it uses the updated logstash.yml:

  `bin/logstash -f second-pipeline.conf --path.data /path/to/second/instance/data`

Comment: thank you. I managed to make it work with your explanation.

Comment: You're welcome :)